# Clear all content in XmlTextWriter and StringWriter

Tags: c#, xmltextwriter, stringwriter

I want to clear all of content in XmlTextWriter and StringWriter. Flush() didn't work out.

`XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();`
`StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();`
`XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);`

`xw.WriteStartElement("AddPhoneQual");`
`xw.WriteElementString("Type", "B");`
`xw.WriteElementString("PhoneNumber", bookingDetails.PassengerList[0].PhoneNumber);`
`xw.WriteEndElement();` // End AddPhoneQual

`doc.LoadXml(sw.ToString());`

Now, i need to clear all of content and start to write in clear xw.

`xw.Flush();`
`sw.Flush();`

They didn't work.

Answer (score 16):

You'd think there would be an intuitive way to do this, but....

A [solution I found](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/537a128e-4518-491b-af5c-51dfd2d6074d/) suggests the following:

```
// make a StringWriter, and fill it with junk
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
sw.Write("Don't want to see this");

// and HERE IS THE MAGIC
StringBuilder sb = sw.GetStringBuilder();
sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);

// your StringWriter is now empty!
```

This worked for me (in the same situation as you -- using an `XmlTextWriter` that dumps to the `StringWriter`).

Perhaps somebody has an intuitive answer for why nothing like this is built-in.

Comment: It's been pointed out (thanks, @PeteB) that you can initialize StringBuiler with a length, allowing us to simplify by replacing the two StringBuilder lines with: sw.GetStringBuilder().Length = 0;

Comment: Or you could just do sw.GetStringBuilder().Clear();

Comment: I don't like it, but it works. Thanks!